# How to manage Firebase Authentication in a JavaEE project?

Tags: java, firebase-authentication, wildfly

I'm using JavaEE and JSF in project to handle some data. I'm also using Firebase as Authentication mechanism, that is used also as part of the RestAPI project. This is the lines of code used in the `AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter`:

```
try {
            FirebaseToken decodedToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(token);
            account = new FirebaseAccount(decodedToken.getUid(), decodedToken.getName(), decodedToken.getEmail(),
                    decodedToken.getPicture());
            container.setProperty("account", decodedToken);
            request.setAttribute("account", account);
            System.out.println("successful login");
        } catch (FirebaseAuthException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Token oauth2 not valid");
        }
```

As method to login the user I'm using this self implementation of Firebase:

```
public boolean signInWithUsernameAndPassword(String email, String password, IFirebaseLoginHandler handler) {
    FirebaseLoginUsernameAndPasswordRequest request = new FirebaseLoginUsernameAndPasswordRequest(email, password);
    Unirest.config().setObjectMapper(new GsonObjectMapper());
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> reponse = Unirest.post(URL_SIGN_IN + API_LEY).body(request).asJson();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    if (reponse.getStatus() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        FirebaseLoginResponse loginResponse = gson.fromJson(reponse.getBody().toString(),
                FirebaseLoginResponse.class);
        handler.onSuccess(loginResponse);
        return true;
    } else {
        FirebaseLoginErrorPassword errorPassword = gson.fromJson(reponse.getBody().toString(),
                FirebaseLoginErrorPassword.class);
        handler.onError(errorPassword);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem of this self implementation is that I'm not handle the refresh token so after one hour the code is expired. Is there any Java library that I can use in my JSF project?
In all case, how Can I handle the refresh token mechanism?

Comment: Hi, I don't see anything JSF related in this question. And by tagging it wildfly, you sort of suggest it works in e.g. glassfish or plain tomcat or...

Comment: there is no JSF since the method siginWithUsernameAndPassword is called within an xhtml file, where username and password is set by it doesn't change the scope of my request.

Comment: If JSF has done its work by passing the username/password to the server, the consequence is that JSF is not a part of the problem. Hence no need to add a JSF tag or use it in the question.

Comment: The problem is still part of the JSF, since the front-end is java/jsf. By the way I think the problem is not the tag used, but how to solve the problem mentioned.

Comment: How did you embed these android libraries into your java project?

Comment: The siginWithUsernamdAndPassword method is self done I didn't import any Android library, since I should use a Java library into the JSF component.

Comment: @Kukeltje any hints?

Comment: No since I don't user firebase...